# javascript .replace() method with mulltiple replacements

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, replace

I want to iterate through a list of values in comma separated string and modify and append the string for each value. Example:

```
    // get input text, convert 
    mySQLtext =  "Select * from filename@@"

    // get substitution value (what to replace)
    mySubstitutonToken =  "@@"

    // get substitution values (comma separated)
    mySubstituton =  "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9"

    // break string into array
    mySubstitutonArray = mySubstituton.split(",");  

    // iterate and replace
    $.each(mySubstitutonArray, function(index, val) {                           
         myVal = mySQLtext.replace(mySubstitutonToken, val);                                    

        // put on screen
        $("#output_text").append(myVal + '<br>');                   

    });
```

output:

```
Select * from filename1
Select * from filename2
Select * from filename3
Select * from filename4
Select * from filename5
Select * from filename6
Select * from filename7
Select * from filename8
Select * from filename9
```

**Question**

If input text had multiple occurrences of substitution value, how would I handle this? Having trouble combining regex syntax with variable names...

Example:
    mySQLtext =  "Select field@@ from filename@@"

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

By replacing all occurrences instead of just one:

```
myVal = mySQLtext.replace(new RegExp(mySubstitutionToken,"g"), val);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using 'g' (global) flag in regexp is required here. 
You do this like this: `new RegExp(expression, 'g')` or `/literalExpression/g`

```js
const token = '@@';
const substitutions = '1,2,3,4,5,6,7';
const template = 'SELECT field@@ FROM file@@';

const output = substitutions
  .split(',')
  .map(num => template.replace(
    new RegExp(token,'g'), 
    num
  ))
  
console.log(output.join('\n'))
```